# Cross-Thread problem - filling FlowLayoutPanel in two instances of a class from a List<Button> in another class

Tags: c#, multithreading

So my problem is as follows: I manages to invoke the filling of the flowLayoutPanel with Buttons, but they refuse to appear in both of the instances of the form. Process being I read in from a db through a SQL query, and fill a List with the results. I then get that list as an args for making them into buttons and store those buttons in an List. I then want to use this List to populate a FlowLayoutPanel in another class which I have made to instances of. Problem arises here where I can only seem to fill one of them at a time (second one that is called).

The class that creates the instances:

```
public class Oppsett
{
    KjokkenSkjerm screenOne;
    KjokkenSkjerm screenTwo;
    public StatusSkjerm customerScreen;

    List<Button> buttonArray = new List<Button>();
    System.Timers.Timer refreshTimer;
    Thread threadTo;


    int counter = 0;
    List<Button> sendArrayEn = new List<Button>();
    List<Button> sendArrayTo = new List<Button>();

    public Oppsett()
    {
        customerScreen = new StatusSkjerm();
        screenOne = new KjokkenSkjerm(customerScreen);
        screenTwo = new KjokkenSkjerm(customerScreen);

        screenOne.Show();
        screenTwo.Show();
        customerScreen.Show();

        refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
        refreshTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        refreshTimer.AutoReset = true;
        refreshTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void addBongAsBtn(List<Bong> bongl)
    {
        Bong bon = new Bong();

        for (int i = 0; i < bongl.Count; i++)
        {
            Button nextBong = new Button();
            bon = bongl[i];

            nextBong.Text = bon.bongInfo[0][0].ToString();
            nextBong.Size = new Size(186, 186);
            nextBong.Tag = bon;
            nextBong.Click += selectedBong_ClickEvent;

            if (buttonArray.Count == 0)
            {
                buttonArray.Add(nextBong);
            }
            else
            {
                bool exists = false;

                for (int j = 0; j < buttonArray.Count(); j++)
                {
                    Bong bb = (Bong)buttonArray[j].Tag;
                    if ((int)bb.bongInfo[0][0] == (int)bon.bongInfo[0][0]) 
                    {
                        exists = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if (exists == false)
                {
                    buttonArray.Add(nextBong);
                }
            }

        }

        screenOne.popArray(buttonArray);
        screenTwo.popArray(buttonArray);

    }
```

Then the class KjokkenScreen that contains the popArray method:

```
public void popArray(List<Button> lb)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
            foreach (Button b in lb)
            {
                bongPanel.Controls.Add(b);
            }            
         });                
    });
    newThread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - create another buttonArray so you have buttonArrayOne and buttonArrayTwo. Populate these with separate objects, so read the same info from the select, but when making new objects create new buttonOne and new buttonTwo. Put these in buttonArrayOne and buttonArrayTwo respectively. Continue like this and then populate each screen with each separate array.
Also use something like this as the populating method:
        public void populerArray(List lb)
        {

```
        if (bongPanel.InvokeRequired)
        {
            foreach (Button b in lb)
            {
                buttonList.Add(b);
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { bongPanel.Controls.Add(b); }));

            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Button b in lb)
            {
                bongPanel.Controls.Add(b);

            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else!